# how to show specific time on uikit timepicker

Tags: html, uikit, timepicker

i trying to make timepicker using uikit, here is the docs https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/timepicker.html

here is option for my timepicker `data-uk-timepicker="{start:8, end:22}"`

but it show like this and there are no 22:00. i want to show 08:00 until 22:00

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind i change the uikit js file, here is the code

```
function getTimeRange(start, end) {

    start = start || 0;
    end   = end || 24;

    var times = {'12h':[], '24h':[]}, i, h;

    for (i = start, h=''; i<=end; i++) {

        h = ''+i;

        if (i<10)  h = '0'+h;

        times['24h'].push({value: (h+':00')});
        if(i!=end) {
            times['24h'].push({value: (h+':30')});
        }

        if (i === 0) {
            h = 12;
            times['12h'].push({value: (h+':00 AM')});
            times['12h'].push({value: (h+':30 AM')});
        }

        if (i > 0 && i<13 && i!==12) {
            times['12h'].push({value: (h+':00 AM')});
            times['12h'].push({value: (h+':30 AM')});
        }

        if (i >= 12) {

            h = h-12;
            if (h === 0) h = 12;
            if (h < 10) h = '0'+String(h);

            times['12h'].push({value: (h+':00 PM')});
            times['12h'].push({value: (h+':30 PM')});
        }
    }

    return times;
}
```